# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sin \left( (2 + \sqrt 3 )^n\pi\right)$ for $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients, limits-without-lhopital

> Evalulate $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sin \bigl( (2 + \sqrt 3 )^n\pi \bigr) \quad \text{ for } n \in \mathbb N$$

This question appeared in my high school exam.

My first idea was as $n$ is an integer then the value must change abruptly for every increase in $n$ which makes the function discontinuous and so the limit does not exist.

But there is another method that proves the limit to be $0$.

Solution :
$$
(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n=2m,m\in I^*
$$

\begin{align}
\therefore \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\Big((2+\sqrt{3})^n\pi\Big)
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin\Big((2m-(2-\sqrt{3})^n)\pi\Big)\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin\Big(2m\pi-(2-\sqrt{3})^n\pi\Big)\\
&=-\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin\Big((2-\sqrt{3})^n\pi\Big)\\
&=-\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin\Bigg(\frac{\pi}{(2+\sqrt{3})^n}\Bigg)\\
&=0
\end{align}

(original images [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFLHY.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU1O7.png))

So, where did I go wrong.

Comment: Note that you are taking the limit of a sequence, not a function. Do you know how the limit of a sequence is defined?

Comment: @Brian But that doesn't change the method of evaluation.

Comment: Yes it does. If the limit was taken where $n\in\mathbb{R}$ then this limit does not exist as you stated. If instead $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then the limit evaluates to $0$.

Comment: ok, thank you I realized as n tends to infinity 2 + $\sqrt 3$ will tend to an even integer.

Answer (score 6):

Note that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left((2+\sqrt 3)^n \right) $$
is not the same as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left((2+\sqrt 3)^n \pi\right) $$